# How to get reference to unnamed array from json

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting this back from the server:

```
{"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Name greg@gmail.com is already taken.","Email 'greg@gmail.com' is already taken."]}}
```

How do I reference the first item of the array in JS?  The debugger tells me that ModelState is an object, but there seems to be no name for the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the first item of your unnamed array like this:

```js
var jsonString = {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Name greg@gmail.com is already taken.","Email 'greg@gmail.com' is already taken."]}};

console.log('first item: ', jsonString.ModelState[''][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

if test = {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"":["Name greg@gmail.com is already taken.","Email 'greg@gmail.com' is already taken."]}}

then your array is at test['ModelState'][""]